# Is Polars not as fast as expected for embarrassingly parallel problem

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

Start with some benchmarking results comparing with Pandas.

```
import time
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

n_index = 1000
n_group1 = 30
n_group2 = 100
n_obs = 30000000

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "index": np.random.randint(0, n_index, size=n_obs),
        "group1": np.random.randint(0, n_group1, size=n_obs),
        "group2": np.random.randint(0, n_group2, size=n_obs),
        "x": np.random.normal(0, 1, n_obs),
        "y": np.random.normal(0, 1, n_obs),
        "z": np.random.normal(0, 1, n_obs),
    }
)

start = time.perf_counter()
df.groupby(["group1", "group2"]).agg(
    [
        pl.mean("x").alias("mean_x"),
        pl.std("x").alias("std_x"),
        pl.mean("y").alias("mean_y"),
        pl.std("y").alias("std_y"),
        pl.mean("z").alias("mean_z"),
        pl.std("z").alias("std_z"),
    ]
)
time.perf_counter() - start

>>> 0.3957360839

df2 = df.to_pandas()

start = time.perf_counter()
df2.groupby(["group1", "group2"])[["x", "y", "z"]].agg(["mean", "std"])
time.perf_counter() - start

>>> 4.1365939596
```

It can be seen that for the same task above, Polars performance is 10x faster than Pandas.

My system for this benchmarking has 32 cores. And, this task is embarrassingly parallel in the sense that I can split up `df2` based on `group1` and then spawn 30 processes and let Pandas handle one `group1` in one process. Including potential overheads over splitting and spawning, I may get similar or even better performance this way. So, my question is that for embarrassingly parallel, Polars performance edge may be easily eliminated by doing parallel computation in another way?

In another words, 10x performance gain in a 32-core system cannot be considered as a performance gain if the task on hand is embarrassingly parallel, given Polars claims that it tries to use all resources during computation?

Or I have some misunderstandings about Polars and parallelism computing. If so, please correct me.

One real use-case is that say I have 30 files under one folder, each with name `sample_i.parquet` corresponding `group1=i` in `df`. And, the result I want to achieve is to generate another 30 files each with columns' `mean` and `std` information.

There are three ways I can achieve this real world task:

1. Use Polars `scan_parquet` to read all files together and assign `group1` for each file to create one giant dataframe and then do `groupby`.
2. Spawn 30 processes, each of which just read one file and calculate column mean and std and finally generate another file using Pandas.
3. Same as 2 but using Polars.

I will do the benchmarking later, but what I expect is that performance-wise: 1 < 2 ~= 3.

If 2 ~= 3 (will do the benchmarking later), then does it mean that Polars can not really gain us much performance for large embarrassingly task?

The reason I expect 2 ~= 3 is that both can really utilize all my cores.

Comment: have you tried what you're suggesting? curious if it actually works the way you think it will

Comment: The performance gain just from going parallel should be capped at 6x as your output has 6 columns. That you realize 10x shows the power of polars optimizations especially as the aggregations you're doing in pandas ought to use numpy vectorization. Do this again with a multiple of 32 columns of output.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Why 6x cap? As I understand Polars, I think the calculations/computations for groups in groupby context are also parallelized?

Answer (score 4):

A groupby is certainly not embarrassingly parallel. The group rows (in some form, can be an aggregated state) have to be synchronized between all threads.

> Excluding potential overheads over splitting and spawning

How do you split the groups over the threads in pandas and processes? Determining the groups is one of the most expensive things of a groupby and now you leave it out of the equation.

### Splitting groups

You also mention you split only by `group1` over the cores. This will lead to a wrong result as the groupby must be over `group1` and `group2`. If you only partition by `group1`, tuples from `group2` may be scattered around all partitions and your result would be incorrect.

Getting incorrect results faster is always easy.

I think you must reconsider your benchmark as I am fairly positive you are not comparing apples with apples.

### Edit

An edit because you changed your question.

You propose:

1. Use Polars scan_parquet to read all files together and assign group1 for each file to create one giant dataframe and then do groupby.
2. Spawn 30 processes, each of which just read one file and calculate column mean and std and finally generate another file using Pandas.

1 is not the same as 2. 1 is much, much more expensive.

If you want to do 2 in polars, you can.

```py
queries = []

for file in my_files:
    q = pl.scan_parquet(file).select(
        pl.mean("x").alias("mean_x"),
        pl.std("x").alias("std_x"),
        pl.mean("y").alias("mean_y"),
        pl.std("y").alias("std_y"),
        pl.mean("z").alias("mean_z"),
        pl.std("z").alias("std_z"),
    )
    queries.append(q)
  

# runs all queries embarrassingly parallel
pl.collect_all(queries)
```

Comment: One typo in my original post, I meant 'including'.

Comment: My post is very initial. Modified the real use case.

Comment: So you only split by group1 and not group1 and group2? Then parts of group2 will be in the wrong group and you result will be wrong. 2 groups likely have a much higher cardinality and high cardinality groupby's are more expensive than low cardinality ones.

Comment: Added a real-world use case, where data are actually separate already.

Comment: Updated my answer. In such a case it can be done embarrassingly parallel indeed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will do a benchmarking later. But in such a case, can we expect 2 and 3 (2 in polars as you suggested) have similar performance as they both well-utilize all cores and the performance difference is really the difference between Rust and C/Python (some of pandas backend is in C?). Or using polars sill gain much more performance?